# Jenkins Groovy post build plugin multi line regex on console log

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to create a multi-line regex using the groovy post build plugin in Jenkins.  I can make this work in the normal Jenkins script console, but I'm having trouble translating that to the post build plugin.

Here is the text I want to grab from the console log:

```
def string """
 TEST SUMMARY:
 [java]  ------------------------------------------------------------
 [java]       268 tests in 69 groups
 [java]       1 errors
 [java]       0 failures
"""
```

This line of code will match what I have above in the script console:

```
def match = string =~ /(?ms)(TEST SUMMARY.*?failures)/
```

I've tried several things with the post build plugin including the following:

```
manager.logContains((?ms)(".*TEST SUMMARY:.*?failures"))
```

and

```
def log = manager.build.logFile
def summary = log =~ /(?ms)(TEST SUMMARY.*?failures)/
```

and

```
def log = manager.build.logFile.text
def summary = log =~ /(?ms)(TEST SUMMARY.*?failures)/
```

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason why you're not using `manager.getLogMatcher()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was a typo which was causing the regex to return 0 matches.  For reference, in the event that someone else needs to do this the correct syntax is:

```
def log = manager.build.logFile.text
def summary = log =~ /(?ms)(TEST SUMMARY.*?failures)/
```

From there you can extract the matches or as in my case further parse the match:

```
def total = summary[0] =~ /\d+ tests/
```