# Jenkins + Docker - How To Deal With Versions

Tags: jenkins, docker

I've got Jenkins set up to do 2 things in 2 separate jobs:

1. Build an executable jar and push to Ivy repo
2. Build a docker image, pulling in the jar from the Ivy repo, and push image to a private docker registry

During step 1 the jar will have some version which will be appended to the filename (e.g. my-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT, my-app-1.0-RELEASE, etc.). The problem that I'm facing is that in the Dockerfile we have to pull in the correct jar file based on the version number from the upstream build. Additionally, I would ideally like the docker image to be tagged with that same version number.

Would love to hear from the community about any possible solutions to this problem.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what are you using to build the image? docker CLI?

Comment: Docker Build and Publish: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Docker+Build+and+Publish+plugin

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need a unique version from (1) to refer to in (2).

```
0.1 -> 0.2 -> 0.3 -> ...
```

Not too complicated in terms of how things work together from a build / Docker point of view. I guess the far bigger challenge is to give up SNAPSHOT builds in the development workflow.

With your current Jenkins: *release* every build you create a container for.

Much better alternative: Choose a CI / CD server that uses **build pipelines**. And if you haven't already done so, take a look at the underlaying concept [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DeploymentPipeline.html).

Comment: Which CI/CD servers support pipelines? Jenkins doesn't employ pipelines?

Comment: We are using [go CD](http://www.go.cd/). That's the only CI / CD server that I'm aware of that is build around the concept of pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Groovy Postbulid Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to [extract with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139654/jenkins-groovy-post-build-plugin-multi-line-regex-on-console-log) the exact name of the generated .jar file at the end of step 1.

Then for step 2, you could have a Dockerfile template and replace in it some placeholder with the exact jar name, build the image and push it to your registry.

Or, if you don't use a Dockerfile you could have in your Docker registry a premade Docker image which has everything but the jar file and add the jar to it with those steps:

- create a container from the image
- add the jar file into the container using the [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/) command
- [commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) the container into a new image
- [push](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/push/) the new image to your docker registry

Answer (score 0):

Same need by my customer. We ended up by putting placeholders in the Dockerfile, which are replaced using sed just before the `docker build`.
This way, you can use the version in multiple locations, either in the `FROM` or in any filenames.

Example:

```
FROM custom:@placeholder@

ENV VERSION @placeholder@

RUN wget ***/myjar-${VERSION}.jar && ...
```

Regarding the consistency, a unique version is used:

- from a job parameter (Jenkins)
- to build the artifact (Maven)
- to tag the Docker image (Docker)
- to tag the Git repository containing the Dockerfile (Git)

Comment: This works, but the unfortunate thing is that working on and testing the Dockerfile becomes a pain. Thoughts on that?

Comment: This implies indeed to use always the same process to build (artifact & image) and tag (image & repo). Always in the same way, which is far from being a bad idea. Great for consistency of your images. And it avoids performing wild and hand-made builds on occasionnal servers. Once written (and tested of course), the way you build an image remains the same, so testing the Dockerfile is not particularly relevant to me.